# Creating view with internal n-references

Tags: mysql, sql

For a CMS system I'm trying to make an elegant way of searching the user-provided url in the article-relation.

I have two tables: one which holds articles (`cms_article`) and another one which holds the language specific content (`cms_content`) of the article.
So 1 line in `cms_article` can have multiple tupples in `cms_content` as it represents different language representations of the article.

Different articles can also be nested by the `reference` column, which refers to the id column in `cms_article` If it's a top-level article this `cms_article.ref` = *NULL*

The tables:

```
cms_article  id  | ref | published  
cms_content  cid | aid | lang      | url | browserTitle | content | etc etc
```

From these two tables I would like to make a view which can be used to look up an URL. So I would like to construct an totalURL field for every given tupple in `cms_article` with every parent/ref as part of the URL.

For instance, lets review this structure of pages/articles:

```
AID  English                             Dutch                               More languages
1    /Products                           /Producten
4    /Products/Product-2                 /Producten/Product-2
7    /Products/Product-2/screenshots     /Producten/Product-2/afbeeldingen
34   /Products/Product-2/pricing         /Producten/Product-2/prijzen
12   /Products/Product-5                 /Producten/Product-5
6    /About-us                           /Over-ons
```

Each line represents an article and 1 tuple in the `cms_article` relation. The URL-field comes from the corresponding `cms_content.url` field.

How can I aggregate the totalURL of each tuple as a view so it produces a view like this:

**cms_view**:

```
aid      = article ID       = integer
lang     = language         = NL|EN|... 
totalURL = agregated URL    = /products/product-2/pricing
```

For the above example it must generate the following table:

```
1  | EN | /Products
1  | NL | /Producten
4  | EN | /Products/Product-2
4  | NL | /Producten/Product-2/afbeeldingen
etc etc
```

Off course I can traverse every single tuple in `cms_content` and find the reference (and repeat this for every level and every tuple) in PHP. But as this puts a lot of stress on the server I'm looking for an elegant sql solution like a view.

**Edit**

This is how far I came, and I feel I'm very close. Seeking a solution for: combining `url` and `parentURL` to one field. And how to do this for three levels deep.

```
SELECT 
a.id AS aid, c.lang, a.ref,
c.url,
(
    SELECT c2.url
    FROM cms_content AS c2
    WHERE c2.aid = a.ref
    AND
    c2.lang = c.lang
) AS parentURL
FROM cms_content AS c
LEFT JOIN cms_article AS a ON c.aid = a.id
WHERE a.domain = 'some.url'
AND a.published =1
ORDER BY aid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all your languages, you can concatenate subqueries.

Example:

```
SELECT
aid
, CONCATENATE( 
  CASE WHEN (SELECT langcode FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'EN')
  THEN 
    CONCATENATE(
    (SELECT langcode FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'EN')
    , '|')
  ELSE ''
  END,
  CASE WHEN (SELECT langcode FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'DU')
  THEN 
    CONCATENATE(
    (SELECT langcode FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'DU')
    , '|')
  ELSE ''
  END) as language
, CONCATENATE( 
  CASE WHEN (SELECT totalUrl FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'EN')
  THEN 
    CONCATENATE(
    (SELECT totalUrl FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'EN')
    , '|')
  ELSE ''
  END,
  CASE WHEN (SELECT totalUrl FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'DU')
  THEN 
    CONCATENATE(
    (SELECT totalUrl FROM cms_article x WHERE a.aid = x.aid AND language = 'DU')
    , '|')
  ELSE ''
  END) as agregatedUrl
FROM cms_content a
```

Comment: I don't know all of my languages. This can be only one two or even 5 languages...

Comment: You can use CASE to check if subquery retrieves data, then concatenate it or not. This is the only way that I can think to achieve what you want, but I think that it will increase your SQL cost. (I edited my answer including the CASE's)

Comment: Hmm that does not look elegant.... I've updated my question with what I've come up to right now.